# How to update time?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to update Time every time I add a data in my tkinter to mysql the time it enter is the time i run my python code in terminal.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import pymysql
from datetime import date , datetime

class DataEntryForm:

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry('600x500+0+0')
        self.root.configure(background='gainsboro')

        #Variable Declaration
        BluetoothAddress=StringVar()
        curr_time=datetime.now()
        Time=curr_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        Date=date.today()
    def addData():
        if BluetoothAddress.get()=='':
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror('No Bluetooth Address','Please Enter Bluetooth Address')
        else:
            sqlCon = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='GAEPCI2020',database='heshevo')
            cur = sqlCon.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT into datam5 values(%s,%s,%s)",
            (BluetoothAddress.get(),
            Time,
            Date))
            sqlCon.commit()
            update()
            sqlCon.close()
           #tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Data Entered Succesfully', 'Bluetooth Address Entered Succesfully')
```

Comment: Well, what about calling `curr_time = datetime.now()` when you call your method to add the data. With your code `curr_time` is only updated when you initiate an instance of `DataEntryForm`. By the way `Time` is not a very good name, better `curr_time_string` ..., `curr_time_string = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen I want to update the curr_time  every time  i add data in my tkinter application. The problem is it is only updated when i run my python code.

Comment: Yes that is what I say. Show me the method where you add data in the tkinter app... the line `curr_time_string = datatime.now().strftime('%H:%M%S')` should be in this method ...

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen please see the code I edited and add the add data function. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. As Bruno Vermeulen mentioned, your init function is only called when the class is instanciated, and never again afterwards, so move the datetime.now() into the addData function so the time is calculated each time when the function is called. I assume you modified this code from someone else, just as a tip, i would recommend starting from scratch to understand the basic concepts of how classes work. You can test such stuff pretty easy, just remove the bluetooth and mysql code and start with a minimal example and datetime, call some function to see if the time changes etc.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import pymysql
from datetime import date , datetime

class DataEntryForm:

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry('600x500+0+0')
        self.root.configure(background='gainsboro')

        #Variable Declaration
        BluetoothAddress=StringVar()

    def addData():
        if BluetoothAddress.get()=='':
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror('No Bluetooth Address','Please Enter Bluetooth Address')
        else:
            sqlCon = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='GAEPCI2020',database='heshevo')
            cur = sqlCon.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT into datam5 values(%s,%s,%s)",
            (BluetoothAddress.get(),
             datatime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'),
             date.today()))
            sqlCon.commit()
            update()
            sqlCon.close()
           #tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Data Entered Succesfully', 'Bluetooth Address Entered Succesfully')
```

Comment: You should add `self` to the method `addData`  and I am sure `BluetoothAddress=StringVar()` should be `self.BluetoothAddress=StringVar()` + the same in `addData` like `(self.BluetoothAddress.get()`, etc. Have you tried to run it?